# Selenium Webdriver-java: i am getting unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (702, 605). Other element would receive the click

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

Please suggest how can I fix this thing.

**Java code:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@data-fieldname='contact_name']")));
element.click();
```

Comment: Please refer this thread  :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300354/selenium-web-driver-chrome-exception-element-is-not-clickable-at-point/33235868#33235868

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to wait still a element is visible(instead of clickable). You can do that like shown below

```
WebDriverWait myWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 45);
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> conditionToCheck = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
            return (input.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@data-fieldname='contact_name']").size() > 0);
        }
    };
    myWait.until(conditionToCheck)
```

;