# selenium web driver chrome exception element is not clickable at point

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I get an exception on web elements click() method.
element is not clickable at point. Other element would receive the click.
on applying scrollTo javascript method before clicking web element.

```
WebElement row;  
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.className("transparent"));
 Iterator<WebElement> i=element.iterator(); 

      while (i.hasNext()) {

        row = i.next();
         js.executeScript("window.scrollTo("+row.getLocation().getX()+","+row.getLocation().getY()+");");   
        row.click();   
     }
```

Comment: Seems your page didnt complete loading yet

Comment: page is loaded cause if element is clicked without scrolling it works fine

Comment: I guess add some delay before click. It's a known issue with Chromedriver since the execution is fastest on this browser

Comment: It's a known issue in chrome driver binary. It marked as won't fix. FYI, https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2766 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error. Many worked/possible solutions are provided by the users over there. #85 worked for me. Hope this helps you.